# how to run a C code with argc argv from python?

Tags: python, c, cpython

I need to run my c code from python, usually as adviced  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376397/executing-a-c-script-in-python) I do this and works perfectly:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["./code", "args", "to", "code"])
```

I would like to run the code that in order to run needs argv, as a number,
so for instance normally from shell I should call simply:

```
./code #certainNumber
```

I would like to pass a string at the call function, like:

```
D=1
str = "./code %d"(%D)
call([str, "args", "to", "code"])
```

obviously this does not work.
I would like to chose from python the parameter that I need to insert in my c code.

thanks

Comment: You MUST read the subprocess module documentation.

Comment: You can pass a number, but you can't pass argv itself.  argv is handled automatically.

Comment: `call(["./code", str(variableContainingNumber), "other", "args"])`, perhaps?

Comment: A side note: if you feel like experimenting, cython is getting very good at doing things like these.

Comment: @twalberg, can we call directly call(["C:\Users\Documents\sample.c"]) ?

Comment: @Anjali No. C code needs to be compiled into a runable binary program first - otherwise it's just a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As twalberg said this works perfectly:

```
call(["./code", str(variableContainingNumber), "other", "args"])
```

Answer (score -1):

You could always do the following

```
import os

# arguments is some list of arguments as strings
output = os.system(processname + " ".join(arguments))
```