# How to implement a python script to interact with a C program

Tags: python, c, scripting

I am running a simple C program that takes inputs from user from the console and does required operation. 
          So I would want to automate the process.Rather than the user feeding the input,is there a way where a python script can call these values(user feed) from a list and help run the C program.

Comment: Have you tried anything??

Comment: Yes there are ways to run external programs from a Python script, and write to them like a file to write to the externals standard input, and read from its standard output. [Read about the `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing a C script in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376397/executing-a-c-script-in-python)

Comment: I haven't tried,because I do not know how to approach the problem.I will surely go through the subprocess module.Thank you all.Any more ideas are most welcome.