# How to compile .c file and .f (fortran) file into .pyd

Tags: python, c, fortran, gfortran, f2py

I have an old c and fortran application i need to convert to a python library that we could use on windows.

i could use gcc and gfortran to compile the .c and .f files to .o files and then compile all of them to a .so file which works as a charm.

```
gcc -c -fPIC 1.c $PYTHON_INCLUDE
gfortran -Wall -Wsurprising -W -c -fPIC 2.f 3.f 4.f
gfortran -shared 1.o 2.o 3.o 4.o -lc -o mylib
```

But i now to need to convert them to a .pyd file.
I tried to use the f2py from numpy.
But `f2py -c 1.c 2.f 3.f 4.f -m mylib`
could not compile them correctly.

There are a lot of "undeclared" errors.
Any recommends?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing a C program in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376397/executing-a-c-program-in-python)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html

Comment: well, they might both work, but i need to compile it as a library, so i could  call it from other apps, and it seems .pyd is the best choice.